# How to add CSS3 animation to a button when its icon is changed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to have CSS transition for a button when the font-awesome icon inside the button changes i.e. using jQuery one icon is replaced with the other.

To give a better understanding of this, here is my HTML:

```
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-lg"></i>
     </button>
```

The jQuery that replaces the icon:

```
$(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $('body').toggleClass("navbar-is-active");
        $('.navbar-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-navicon');
        $('.navbar-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-remove');
    });
```

The CSS styles for the button and CSS transition:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    width: 81px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #c4414f!important;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 29px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background-color: #FFF;
        height: 3px;
        border-radius: 0;
    } 
    .navbar-toggle.active {
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000;
        box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px 0px #333333;
    }

.navbar-toggle {
    color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
    .navbar-toggle i {
        font-size: 24px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
```

But the transition is not working on the button when the menu icon is changed to an 'X'. What am I doing wrong?
I have made a Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/471L8dfd/

As requested, an example of the type of transition i am looking to add to the nav button:

[image: Example of Transition]

Comment: What is it that you want the animation to do?

Comment: You don't have any specific CSS for any of the classes you toggle, so there is not much to transition.

Comment: yes, that is the thing. basically when the navbar icon is changed I want it to have a transition effect like a fade for example.

Comment: You should specify the type of transition you are looking for in your question (add through edit). This will improve the quality of your question.

Comment: What are we supposed to click in the fiddle, there's no output in the output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` functions would do the trick:

```
 $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("active");
     $('body').toggleClass("navbar-is-active");
     $('.navbar-toggle i').fadeOut(100, function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('fa-navicon');
     })
     $('.navbar-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-remove').fadeIn(150);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/471L8dfd/3/

Edit:
Note that class is toggled after `fadeOut` is order to prevent popping of icons and that the first animation speed (at 100ms) belongs to current icon `fadeOut` and the second to the next icon `fadeIn`. Your total animation speed is these two values combined (100+150 = 250ms)

Comment: I have just edited my question and provided an example. Your answer is good, any chance it could be closer to the provided example? Thank you

Comment: You mean in terms of transition speed or the transition (e.g. linear, ease ...)?

Comment: Here is an update with a few editable variables. https://jsfiddle.net/471L8dfd/4/